# Auth.auth().signIn(withCustomToken: ) { (user, error) received callback is nil

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, linkedin-api

I am trying to authenticate LinkedIn with Firebase but I am unable to understand the step needed to get the custom token to access Firebase authentications.

Here is my function to sign the user in:

```
func signInWithCustomToken() {
    let customToken = user.id!
    Auth.auth().signIn(withCustomToken: customToken) { (user, error) in

        print(user)
    }
}
```

But this is printing out

> nil

I have looked at these questions: [LinkedIn login with custom token ( ERROR_INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46167501/linkedin-login-with-custom-token-error-invalid-custom-token) and [Firebase Auth (with Custom Token, for Linkedin) returns a user with no email and no data (only uid)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45217730/firebase-auth-with-custom-token-for-linkedin-returns-a-user-with-no-email-and). But still unable to get this to work.

Comment: Where are you generating the custom token? You need to generate a custom JWT using Firebase. You can do this using the Admin SDK, documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens).

Comment: I am generating the custom token through the users UID which is their LinkedIn ID. I already have the SDK installed on my app and called `FirebaseApp.configure()` on my appDelegate. I'm quite confused about the JWT part.

Comment: You need a separate server to get the custom token. It cannot be done from the client. The documentation for custom auth: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/custom-auth mentions this. You can use something like Cloud Functions for Firebase. See the samples here: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples for a couple examples of custom auth using Cloud Functions.

Comment: According to this documentation (https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/linkedin-auth) I need to set a Blaze plan?

Comment: Yes, to be able to perform HTTP requests to external services from a Cloud Function. But you don't have to use Cloud Functions to generate the custom token. You can use whatever server or serverless option you prefer. The point is, it cannot be done from the iOS app itself.